# Run matlab 2008 command from Matlab 2010?

Tags: command-line, matlab

I'm running Matlab 2010 and there's some function I want to run from my Matlab 2008.
Is it possible to do it directly from the command line of matlab 2010 instead of starting Matlab 2008, type in the command and see what comes up?

p.s. I need this because of the version differences in toolboxes I have for the two Matlab - the "report" function only runs in matlab 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `!` to call to start the second copy of MATLAB from the first via a shell command, e.g.,

```
!"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2008b\bin\matlab.exe" -r disp(1:5)
```

The `-r` option means "execute the following code on startup".  You could type the name of a script that runs the report there.  See the [startup options help page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f8-4994.html) for more.  (For example, since you are just using that copy of MATLAB as a slave, rather than interacting directly with it, you may want to turn off the JVM for speed.)

Comment: @richie-cotton: any possibility replacing the ! with some command, i.e. `foo("c:\test.exe", "disp(1:5)")` instead of `!"c:\test.exe" disp(1:5)`? Thanks!

Comment: @shahar: Use `system` if you prefer functional syntax.